# Having issues putting two Texts in a column inside a CircleAvatar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I am making a personal expense app. Here I made a ListView of ListTiles(wrapped in card) containing information about transactions. Inside the ListTiles I used a CircleAvatar containing a column with two texts inside it. But the Issue is I cant get them to be properly centered. For some reason, they are being displayed one at the top and one at the bottom of the CircleAvatar. Why is this happening and how can I fix this. Thank you.

Screenshot can be found at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpYyG.jpg

```
class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> _transactions;

  TransactionList(this._transactions);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      child: (_transactions.isEmpty)
          ? Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Nothing.... \:\'\(',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 250,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/waiting.png'),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: FittedBox(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text('TK'),
                              Text('\n${_transactions[index].amount}')
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      '${_transactions[index].title}',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_transactions[index].time) +
                          '\nTk.${_transactions[index].amount}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    isThreeLine: true,
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: _transactions.length,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try setting the column `mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center,`

Answer (score 0):

you should set `mainAxisAlignemnt` and `CrossAxisAlignment` of the columen. use this:

```
Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text('TK',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                              Text('\n${_transactions[index].amount}',textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                            ],
                          ),
```

also, you can use `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` for having equal space between two texts in the vertical direction, or you can use a `SizedBox` like:

```
SizedBox(height:8), // for vertical space
```